# Ionic 3 filter nested JSON with ionic searchbar

Tags: json, ionic3, searchbar

I have a question how to use ionic searchbar to filter items in a nested JSON object. As I've tried to filter the `header` item it worked perfectly fine but it does not work for the `name` wrap inside the `brands`.

```
{
"items": [{
        "header": "A",
        "brands": [{ "name": "Apple", "id": "1" }, { "name": "Adidas", "id": "2" }]
    },
    {
        "header": "B",
        "brands": [{ "name": "Bose", "id": "3" }, { "name": "Boss", "id": "4" }, { "name": "Birkenstock", "id": "5" }]
    },
    {
        "header": "M",
        "brands": [{ "name": "McDonalds", "id": "6" }]
    }
]
}
```

My `search.ts`:

```
    private result: any[];
  private searchItems: any;
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private http: Http
  ) {
    let localData = this.http.get('assets/search-brand.json').map(res => res.json().items);
    localData.subscribe(data => {
      this.result = data;
    });
    this.initializeItems();
  }

  initializeItems() {
    this.searchItems = this.result;
  }

  getItems(ev: any) {
    // Reset items back to all of the items
    this.initializeItems();

    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.searchItems = this.searchItems.filter((item) => {
        return (item.header.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }
```

My code (`search.html`):

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
<p>{{test}}</p>
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of searchItems; let i = index">
    <ion-list-header>
        {{item.header}}
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let brands of item.brands; let j = index" (click)="selectedBrand(brands.id)">{{brands.name}}</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

This one is working for filtering the `brands.name` it said `.toLowerCase() is not a function`.

Comment: @JensHöpken I've edited the question, when I'm trying to filter the brands.name I got an error said ".toLowerCase()" is not a function.

Comment: `return (item.header.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1)` this code does not filter by `brands.name`?

Comment: @Duannx this one is only able to filter the header not the brands.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON data maybe have some element with `header == null` or does not have `brands` propertive. So to ensure the search work properly, you should handle these case by `if` statement. You need to rewrite filter function to get expected output. 
Try this:

```
this.searchItems = this.searchItems.map((item)=>{
   if(item && item.brands && item.brands.length > 0){
     item.brands = item.brands.filter(brand=>{
      if(!brand.name) return false;
      return brand.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
     });
   }    
   retrun item;   
})
```

Comment: No luck with this also, it said "Unable to get property "filter" of undefined or null reference. :(

Comment: It's work! Thanks for your guidance, but i'm still trying to figure out how is this code working.

Comment: Glad to help. I updated my answer to explain. If you have any question, feel free to ask.